# Scala - fromPublisher is not a member of object akka.stream.scaladsl.Source

Tags: scala, akka, slick

I just started working with akka streams (2.4.6) and slick (3.1.1) in Scala (2.11.7). I'm using Intellij (not sure if that matters but I thought I'd throw it out there).

```
val scanner: DatabasePublisher[Stage] = db.stream(action.transactionally.withStatementParameters(fetchSize = 5000))
val source = Source.fromPublisher(scanner)
```

the problem is on the second line. Intellij is telling me that it cannot resolve symbol "fromPublisher" ... I thought it was IJ being finnicky but when I went to build I got this:

```
Error:(38, 10) value fromPublisher is not a member of object akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
  Source.fromPublisher(scanner)
         ^
```

any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Been fighting with this the whole night and I'm ready to pull my hair out.

Thanks!

Comment: could you show full code snippet

Answer (score 1):

See working example:

```
import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl.Source
import slick.backend.DatabasePublisher
import slick.driver.H2Driver.api._

import scala.concurrent.Await
import scala.concurrent.duration._

case class Emp(id: Int, name: String)

object Demo extends App {

  implicit val system = ActorSystem("Sys")

  val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")

  val empTableQuery = TableQuery[EmployeeTable]
  val insertQuery = empTableQuery ++= Seq(Emp(1, "emp1"), Emp(2, "emp2"), Emp(3, "emp3"), Emp(4, "emp4"))
  val action = DBIO.seq(empTableQuery.schema.create, insertQuery)

  //create schema and insert record
  Await.result(db.run(action), 1000 second)
  // print db record
  Await.result(db.run(empTableQuery.result), 1000 second).foreach(println)
  val publisher: DatabasePublisher[Emp] = db.stream(empTableQuery.result)

  import system.dispatcher

  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  //consume using stream
  println("Steaming data::::::::")
  val source = Source.fromPublisher(publisher).map(emp => emp.id + " : " + emp.name).runForeach(println)

  class EmployeeTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Emp](tag, "emp") {
    val id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey)
    val name = column[String]("name")

    def * = (id, name) <>(Emp.tupled, Emp.unapply)
  }


  source.onComplete(_ => system.terminate())

}
```

**build.sbt**

```
   scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.36",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-hikaricp" % "3.1.1",
  "ch.qos.logback" % "logback-classic" % "1.1.3",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-stream" % "2.4.6",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.5" % "test",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.187"
)
```

**application.conf**

```
h2mem1 = {
  url = "jdbc:h2:mem:test1"
  driver = org.h2.Driver
  connectionPool = disabled
  keepAliveConnection = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying to my question. I found the problem. It wasn't the code.

The problem was in Intellij libraries setup.

I compiled the project with SBT and it worked and ran fine, in spite of the fact that IJ was throwing up all over it.

So I after poking I around I went into Project Structure -> SDK and I noticed that in the SDK libraries, akka-stream-experimental 1.0 jar and a whole slew of other junk.

I deleted those (left the JDK 8 jars). And now everything works!

Thank you anyway!